# Rails 3.2 wicked_pdf image not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

im using Rails 3.2 and wicked_pdf + wkhtmltopdf-binary gem, i am trying to render an image in the pdf but it is not working,

i have tried

```
<%= image_tag "image.png" %>
```

and

```
<img src="/assets/images/image.png">
<img src="/public/image.png">
```

with no success.

The rest of the pdf is rendering good except for images, What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wkhtmltopdf needs to know the full path to the image files and you're supplying relative ones. Either update them to use the full URL, or try the `wicked_pdf_image_tag` helper. I've not tried the latter route, but it is supposed to address what you're trying to do.

Here's a [GH issue](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/36) about it.

Comment: Thank you, it works well both ways, though i cant set a size for the image like with the html attributes height and width.

Comment: `wicked_pdf_image_tag` takes an options hash that you could use to set the height/width in the same way that you would set it with an `image_tag` helper.

Comment: something like this? `<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag('image_logo.png', options = { :width => 300, :height => 200}) %>` i tried that but doesnt work

Comment: Nevermind, it did work, now i have problems with the size of the div html tags that wicked_pdf is displaying but ill add a new question in case i dont find a solution, thank you d_either.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue images weren't rendering in pdf, I found out `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6` has introduced a breaking change that from now onwards local file access will be blocked by default, and to enable it we will have to explicitly add `enable_local_file_access: true` where our pdf is being rendered.
You can follow advance usage instructions from [here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#advanced-usage-with-all-available-options).

Answer (score 0):

I've dealed with this problem before. The solution I found was to return the image location with the request protocol and host, this way:

```rb
%img{src: "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{asset_path('image.png')}" }
```

The image tag (`%img`) i'm using is the one with [haml](http://haml.info/) syntax, the key here is the path route to the image independent of html or haml tags:

```rb
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{asset_path('image.png')}"
```

wkhtmltopdf is like an external agent: needs the absolute path. Hope it helps.